# Javascript CORS blocked but still shows data in packet capture

Tags: javascript, cors

I have written a web app that is served to the browser from the local filesystem. I am attempting to make an HTTP GET request to another domain using jQuery's ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=0",
    dataType: "text",
    data: null,
    success: function(data){
        var x = data;
    },
    error: function(data, err) {
        var x = err;
    }
});
```

In the developer console, I am getting the error, "`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=0. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`"

Now: I understand what this means, and the purpose for this error.

Here's the really weird part: when I take a Wireshark capture of network traffic, I can see that the remote server is, in fact, serving up the content I requested.

Is that the way CORS works? Does it depend entirely on the client receiving data from the server and then refusing to work with it? I haven't found a clear explanation of where CORS is enforced; I expected it to be a server-side error and not a client-side error.

It's frustrating knowing that my browser is getting the data I requested but isn't letting me use it. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: A workaround would constitute a critical security flaw.

Comment: that is why some types of failed xdomain ajax requests still leave log entries on 3rd-party site logs; (non-pre-flight) ajax is essentially write-only to third party URLs, but a lot of coders don't realize the remote got it because the browser covers it up with an error...

Answer (score 1):

CORS depends on the browser and the server. The browser should block the content; the server should respect the OPTIONS verb and return a proper CORS response.

Comment: A browser can't know whether the headers will be there or not. Some kinds of requests aren't pre-flight tested, so those will get back to the client system with all the data and the browser (unless it's seriously broken) will notice the missing headers and throw away everything else.